# Bash prompt changes when using arrow keys sometimes

Tags: bash, ps1

When I use my terminal (iTerm 2 Mac) with my PS1 set to `"\[\e[38;5;117m\W \e[39;38;5;104m\$\e[39;0m\] "` and I use the arrow keys to go through my bash history it sometimes changes my prompt from `~ $` to just the first character of it and whatever command I'm looking at. For example, going to `rvim .bashrc` from `randomDir $ ls`. This problem also persists in the default terminal app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\W` and `\$` should not go inside the `\[...\]`, since `bash` will know how much space each takes up on the terminal.

```
PS1="\[\e[38;5;117m\]\W \[\e[39;38;5;104m\]\$\[\e[39;0m\] "
```

*Only* the characters that make up the ANSI escape sequence (which only instruct the terminal to change colors, without displaying a single additional character) are enclosed in `\[...\]`.

Putting them inside `\[...\]` tells `bash` to ignore their contribution to the length of the prompt, leading to incorrect redraws.